# Problema con Include en C# Linq y tamaño maximo

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

Tengo un pequeño problema con este codigo:

```
var Lista =  from op in SalesOpportunityList
    .Include("SalesOpportunityPhase")
    .Include("Account")
    .Include("Manager")
    .Include("SourceChannel.ChannelType")
    .Include("OpportunityCourses")
    .Include("OpportunityCourses.CourseModType")
    .Include("OpportunityCourses.CourseModType.Course")
    orderby op.State,op.OrderRating ,op.InitialDate descending
    select op;
return Lista;
```

el tema es que al hacer el return lista Me da el siguiente error:
An error occurred while reading from the store provider's data reader. See the inner exception for details.
No se puede crear una fila de tamaño 8068, que es mayor que el tamaño de fila máximo permitido de 8060.

He visto que es por el tema del SQL server que cuando devuelve una consulta tiene limite 8K. El tema es  no se exactamente como hacer un select mas pequeño y que me mantenga la lista con el tipo de datos que es SalesOpportunity

No se si hay una forma de hacer un include mas pequeño o algo por el estilo, porque no necesito todas la propiedades de la entidad mapeada.

Espero que alguien me pueda dar algo de luz en el asunto.

Comment: En serio ocupas todos esos include? igual ni siquiera requieres tantos datos. Bueno, no es necesario que te lleves toda tu base de datos  en una lectura, puedes leer cierta cantidad de registros e ir mostrando por x cantidades. Por ejemplo leer los primeros 200 registros, y darle la opción al usuario de cargar el resto conforme los requiera.

Comment: @Luis entiendo que el problema es de columnas, no de filas. Sergio, prueba a añadir un select despues de cada include, seleccionando las columnas que te interesen

Comment: @Pikoh, tienes razón. Sergio, en vez de tanto include, ¿has probado en hacer joins?

Comment: Hola el tema es que yo no tengo acceso a hacer todo el codigo, y el problema es que si hago join en vez de includes, me lanza esto:Description: No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'System.Linq.IQueryable<smartrt.crmsalesopportunity.datamodels.salesopportunitydatamodel.datamodelentities.SalesOpportunity>' en 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable<smartrt.crmsalesopportunity.datamodels.salesopportunitydatamodel.datamodelentities.SalesOpportunity>'. Ya existe una conversión explícita (compruebe si le falta una conversión)

Comment: En verdad con algo parecido a esto me valdria:
 var Lista =  from op in SalesOpportunityList
  .Include("SalesOpportunityPhase")
  .Include("Account")
  .Include(x=>x.Manager.Name)
  .Include("SourceChannel.ChannelType")
  .Include("OpportunityCourses")
  .Include("OpportunityCourses.CourseModType")
  .Include("OpportunityCourses.CourseModType.Course")
  orderby op.State,op.OrderRating ,op.InitialDate descending
  select op;

Comment: Has probado lo que te dije? `var Lista = from op in SalesOpportunityList .Include("SalesOpportunityPhase").Select(x=>x.Campo que te interesa).Include(....`

Comment: algo asi?
from op in SalesOpportunityList
  .Include("SalesOpportunityPhase")
  .Include("Account")
  .Include("Manager")
  .Select(op=>op.Manager.Name)
  .Include("SourceChannel.ChannelType")
  .Include("OpportunityCourses")
  .Include("OpportunityCourses.CourseModType")
  .Include("OpportunityCourses.CourseModType.Course")
  orderby op.State,op.OrderRating ,op.InitialDate descending
  select op;

Comment: Eso es. Prueba a ver si te funciona asi

Comment: He intentado varias maneras y me devuelve:
Description: 'string' no contiene una definición de 'State' ni se encontró ningún método de extensión 'State' que acepte un primer argumento de tipo 'string' (¿falta una directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)

Comment: De todas maneras, ahora que me fijo, estas mezclando sintaxis linq y de metodos de extensión. O usas uno o el otro, lo contrario suele llevar a equívocos.

Comment: Por ahora lo he solucionado bajando de tamaño uno de los include en la propia tabla SQL server.

Comment: Sergio, muestra como hiciste tu join. Igual si sabes SQL puedes hacer la consulta por medio del lenguaje.

Comment: Gracias la verdad es que de momento lo voy a hacer asi. Pero si me gustaria saber un poco mas de Linq, Sql si uqe se lo que pasa que tengo que hacerlo por medio de una entidades de Linq, al estilo como cuando hacia programacionfuncional